# I am opening a port on a fresh Centos 7 server, but nmap says it's still closed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, sockets, tcp

I have installed a fresh `Centos 7` box on virtualbox running in a bridged network adapter.  I have installed ruby on rails and setup a simple app.  I started the server on port 3000, but when I try to reach it from my host machine hitting the IP I get no response.

On the server I can do a

```
wget "http://127.0.0.1:3000"
```

and I get the right index.html file.  So I figured my port was getting blocked.

So I installed firewalld and issued the following commands

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=3000/tcp --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
firewall-cmd --list-all
```

The list all shows the following ;

```
public (default, active)
interfaces: enp0s3
sources:
services: dhcpv6-client ssh
ports: 3000/tcp 80/tcp
masquerade: no
forward-ports:
icmp-blocks:
rich rules:
```

However when I run nmap I see it's closed

```
sudo nmap -p 3000 127.0.0.1
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-11-26 01:47 EST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000071s latency).
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
3000/tcp closed ppp

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.06 seconds
```

From my host machine I can ping the machine but when I `nmap` to port 3000 it says the host is unreachable.

I don't know how to go any further.  Any thoughts?

Comment: please check selinux mode. If it is enforcing then make it permissive. and try again

Comment: That was a good thing to check.  I have set it to permissive, then tried everything again, started the server back up, opened the ports, and tested nmap, and remote browser.  All are still failing.

Comment: Possibly your rails app isn't binding to the right IP address / interface?

Comment: How would I check that?  Where do I need to look?

Comment: you use getenforce command for check. If it is enforceing. Then use setenforce 0 for temporary make it permissive

Comment: I should have been specific how do I check that the rails app is binding to the right ip address?

Comment: Have you found a answer? I have exactly the same issue (and selinux is disabled)